# FreeRadius clusters?

Tags: linux, сеть, администрирование, freeradius

Дано:
Backend: Пара серверов с Ldap базой пользователей;
Frontend: Один сервер с freeradius;
Все работает на Debian8

Поднять идентичный freeradius сервер на сторонней площадке для отказоустойчивости и собрать из двух кластер.

Собственно вопрос, какими средствами это лучше сделать? лично я подумываю:
haproxy (но тут вопрос он будет tls проксировать прозрачно или ему нужен будет СА с Радиуса?)
либо vrrp между двумя нодами (но как быть если у меня freeradius работает по udp не вызовит ли это проблему с load-balancing?)

Мб у кого-нибудь есть лучше идеи и удачный опыт просьба поделиться им. Заранее благодарен .

Comment: лоад балансинг делается третьим радиус сервером)

Comment: клиенты подключаются через radsec или udp?

Comment: Клиенты подключаются по udp. Уже решил вопрос с помощью anycast bgp. А по поводу lb как это вяжется с установкой tls ? Или lb будет per flow?

Comment: Если один клиент будет попадать в один сервер проблем не будет. Тлс там в нагрузке радиус пакета внутри еап атрибута..